# How can I download a blob from MariaDB 5.5.47 using PHP 7?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

With PHP 5 and MariaDB 5.5.47, the following code would successfully get the name and content (type=longblob) and echo the content:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, content FROM Data WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stmt->closeCursor();

echo $lob;
```

After upgrading to PHP 7, the `$lob` variable is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($lob);`

Comment: When I try to output it, it's empty.

Comment: @Hackerman I specifically get `string(0) ""`

Comment: I've also added printed out the a message if this returns true `extension_loaded('mysqlnd')`, which it does.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's because my upload isn't working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053736/how-can-i-insert-file-from-post-into-longblob-column-using-php-7-and-mysql

Comment: But you have the blob value on your database?

Comment: Well, using MySQL workbench, it looks like the blob has something in it (it shows "BLOB" in the UI versus "null", however, it actually contains 0 bytes.

I've opened another question with regards to uploading/storing a blob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053736/how-can-i-insert-file-from-post-into-longblob-column-using-php-7-and-mysql/40053912#40053912