# How can I insert file from POST into longblob column using PHP 7 and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I'm using PHP 7 and MariaDB 5.5.47 (on CentOS 7) and the following code successfully executes, with no errors:

```
$id = 3;
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'rb');

$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Foo (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $id);
$statement->bindParam(2, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
close($fp);
```

Using MySQL WorkBench it shows the "data" column is "BLOB" (as opposed to null, in the event I insert nothing). When I try to query the data, it's zero bytes. This code worked with PHP 5, but I haven't found any reason why it wouldn't work with PHP 7.

Comment: This code works until I try to upload a larger file (say > 20mb). see my "answer"

Answer (score 1):

Switching to reading the content and passing that in worked.

```
$fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'rb');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_name));
// ...
$statement->bindParam(2, $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB, $size);
```

However, I run into errors about memory when uploading a file that's > 20mb:

> **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 81606320 bytes) in **/var/www/app/API/docs.php**
>   on line **498**

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP way of increasing its memory usage:

ini_set('memory_limit', '210M');

Notice that it already had 128M allocated, and it was trying to allocate 80M more -- is that the size of the file?

Adjust the value in init_set as needed.  BUT... If MySQL is on the same server, then you should tune it downward.  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the likely one to tweak.

Keep in mind that swapping is terrible for performance.